# Echo returned value from count(*) mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot figure out why this does not echo anything. What I am trying to echo is the amount of users in the db table. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM Users");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt -> fetch();
echo $result;
```

Comment: `SELECT count(*) AS cnt` then `echo $result['cnt']`

Comment: try `print_r($result)`. You'll get a better idea of what exactly is being returned.

Comment: is it PDO or MySQLi ? For MySQLi you need to [`bind`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) variables. Or [`get_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php).

Comment: @HAL9000 bind values for what exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having only one column selected, doesn't make the fetch method to return string. In most of the cases it still returns its default fetch - associative array.

You need to alias the column with `AS` in order to access it as column

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM Users");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt -> fetch();
echo $result['cnt'];
```